# In understanding the recursive definitions of $+,\cdot$, using the successor function

Tags: logic, definition, recursion

I am self-studying a course on logic during the summer, and I have a question relating to formulations in my textbook. The section is about recursive definitions, and the construction of $\mathbb{N}$, using the successor function $s$, has just been explained. The examples define addition, multiplication and exponentiation, recursively on $\mathbb{N}$. The following are quotes from the book:

> Addition is defined in a similar manner, in two cases:
>
> $\begin{gather}a+0:=a\\ a+s(n):=s(a+n)\end{gather}$
>
> Addition occurs on the right side of [the second case above]. One therefore says that the definition is "recursive".

**Note**: *$s:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, is the successor function.*

Further down, one can read:

> The definition of [multiplication] brings nothing new, except that one can choose to have the recursion in the first argument, if one wants to:
>
> $\begin{gather}0\cdot a:=0\\ s(n)\cdot a:=(n\cdot a)+a\end{gather}$
>
> In the definition of exponentiation, the recursion has to occur in the second argument:
>
> $\begin{gather}a^0:=1\\ a^{s(n)}:=a^n\cdot a\end{gather}$

**Question(s):** What is meant by the statements "one can choose to have the recursion in the **first argument**, if one wants to" and "In the definition of exponentiation, the recursion has to occur in the **second argument**"? Also, how could we define it differently, so that the def. of $\cdot$ has the recursion in the first/second argument? What exactly is meant by 'argument' here?

**Thoughts:** If they are referring to the arguments of the binary operations of $+$ and $\cdot$, both definitions have the recursion in the first argument, no? I do not see what makes the two definitions different (in the way they are suggesting). As I've understood it, the recursion takes place at "$(n\cdot a)$" and at "$a^n$", does it not?

Comment: Even if you use $(1 + a)^n = 1 + na + {n \choose 2} a^2 + {n \choose 3} a^3 \dots$, you have to define an auxiliary function to compute ${n \choose k}$.  Although I can't prove it off the top of my head, it seems likely that ${n \choose k}$ can't be defined without recurring on $n$.  At some point, even with auxiliary functions, you'll have to make a recursion call on $(n - 1)$.  Not to mention the sum itself recurs on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is which argument (= variable input) is being "broken down" in the recursive definition.

For instance, here's another way to define multiplication recursively:

- $a\cdot 0=0$,
- $a\cdot s(x)=a\cdot x+a$.

To compute $3\cdot 2$, we'd break down the **second argument** (in this case, "$2$"): $$3\cdot 2=3\cdot s(s(0))=3\cdot s(0)+3=3\cdot 0+3+3=0+3+3=6.$$

This is the issue with recursive definitions: the variables have to line up appropriately, so that we can in fact *evaluate* expressions by breaking them down into simpler ones, and eventually arriving at a "base case" (like $a\cdot 0$) which we understand.

By the way, note that in the last equality, we use $a\cdot 0=0$ - but $0\cdot a=0$ wouldn't obviously (in fact, provably wouldn't) get the job done! The $0$ in the base case has to be in the same place as the "breaking down" (= recursing) variable.

---

Both multiplication and addition "split nicely on both sides" - e.g. $s(a)+b=a+s(b)=s(a+b)$, and similarly with $\cdot$. So we can use either the first or the second variable as our recursing variable.

Now what about exponentiation?

Well, we want to give a recursive definition of $exp(a,b)$. Such a definition has a *base case* and a *successor case* (recursion is to *constructions* what induction is to *proofs*). We have two basic options:

- Recursion on the first variable: $exp(0, b)=?$,$\quad exp(s(a), b)=?$.
- Recursion on the second variable: $exp(b,0)=?$,$\quad exp(b, s(a))=?$.

Three of these expressions are easy to evaluate, and we get:

- Recursion on the first variable: $exp(0, b)=0$,$\quad exp(s(a), b)={\color{red}?}$.
- Recursion on the second variable: $exp(b,0)=1$,$\quad exp(b, s(a))=exp(b, a)\cdot b$.

But there's no good way to simplifty $(a+1)^b$! So while recursion on the second variable has a perfectly nice form, recursion on the *first variable* in this case runs into serious problems. (I'm not saying these problems are insurmountable - we could get around this by being a bit clever with binomial coefficients and division - but this shows that recursion on the second variable is clearly the **best** way to define exponentiation recursively.)

Comment: Well, this makes it much clearer, I should've figured, simple as it was, but I think I was starring at what happened on rhs, i.e. I did not think of the recursion as happening on the arguments per se. so I got confused. Also, I will get used to recursive definitions again soon enough. Thank you for an elaborate and well written answer.

Comment: @Christopher.L Thanks! Yeah, one of the things that gets left out a lot (for some reason) when presenting recursive arguments is the bit about recursion happening on a specific variable. Usually the examples that are done in class, in my experience, are *commutative* functions, which obscure the importance of the variable choice.

Comment: When you say "we could get around this by being a bit clever", are you suggesting that it is possible to define $a^n$ without recurring on $n$?  I'd be interested in seeing that.  I'll post it as a question if you prefer. (Edit: actually that might be a redundant question since that is what the poster is already asking).

Answer (score 2):

**"one can choose to have the recursion in the first argument, if one wants to"**

-> that means that you could also choose to define addition this way:

$0+a := a$

$s(n)+a := s(a+n)$

**What exactly is meant by 'argument' here?**

$a$ and $n$ are the arguments of the operator $+$ in the expression $a+n$

**"In the definition of exponentiation, the recursion has to occur in the second argument"?**

*It would not work* to try to define exponentiation with a formula using $a^n$ to define $(s(a))^n$ (just try if that doesn't seem obvious...)